# Problema a la hora de realizar un ejercicio con hilos en Java

Tags: java, hilos

Buenas, hoy en empezado con hilos y ando un poco perdido, he realizado el siguiente código para realizar un programa con dos hilos de nombre "HiloUno" e "HiloDos" de forma que cada uno de ellos visualice los 10 primeros números naturales. Pero creo que lo tengo mal hecho.

Codigo:

```
public class Ejercicio1Hilos extends Thread
{   
    public void run() 
    {
        System.out.println("Hilo1");
        System.out.println("Hilo2");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Ejercicio1Hilos myThread1 = new Ejercicio1Hilos();
        Ejercicio1Hilos myThread2 = new Ejercicio1Hilos();

        for(int i=1;i<=10;i++)
        {
            myThread1.start();
            myThread2.start();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Ambos hilos te están imprimiendo Hilo1 seguido de Hilo2. Deberías primero de estudiar la diferencia entre clase e instancia.

Comment: Basicamente, pasa el ciclo al metodo run() pero dejando los start() en el main(), para que distingas entre hilos agrega un constructor al que le pases en este caso el nombre "Hilo1", "Hilo2", ... "HiloN" y dentro del ciclo solo imprime ese argumento (nombre-del-hilo) mas el numero natural proporcionado por el puntero i.
PD. Consulta lo que puedas acerca del metodo sleep()

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Complementando lo que te escribieron en los comentarios, creo que vas por buen camino, pero la lógica la tienes en los lugares equivocados.

Estás creando e iniciando muy bien los hilos, pero lo que estás haciendo es iniciar ambos hilos 10 veces y cada hilo está imprimiendo

> Hilo1
>   Hilo2

Lo que esto hace es que ocurra una excepción (en el peor de los casos por un `IllegalThreadStateException`) y no te permita continuar. Si no fuera por la excepción, estaría imprimiendo 20 veces lo anterior.

Si no mal entiendo lo que quieres, lo que tienes que hacer es pasar el ciclo que tienes (`for`) adentro del método `run`:

```
public void run() {
    for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
    ...
    }
}
```

y dentro del `for` puedes imprimir el contador mismo:

```
System.out.println(i);
```

Ahora, tomando en cuenta los comentarios que te hicieron, puedes tener un constructor para tu clase que reciba el nombre de tu hilo:

```
private String nombre;

public Ejercicio1Hilos(final String nombre) {
    this.nombre = nombre;
}
```

e imprimir el nombre más el contador:

```
System.out.println(nombre + " " + i);
```

Por último, cuando se crea la instancia de tus hilos, lo haces pasándole el nombre que quieras:

```
Ejercicio1Hilos myThread1 = new Ejercicio1Hilos("Hilo 1");
```

y el resultado final será algo así:

> Hilo 1 1
>   Hilo 2 1
>   Hilo 1 2
>   Hilo 2 2
>   Hilo 1 3
>   Hilo 2 3
>   Hilo 1 4
>   Hilo 1 5
>   Hilo 2 4
>   Hilo 1 6
>   Hilo 2 5
>   Hilo 1 7
>   Hilo 2 6
>   Hilo 1 8
>   Hilo 1 9
>   Hilo 2 7
>   Hilo 1 10
>   Hilo 2 8
>   Hilo 2 9
>   Hilo 2 10

NOTA: Puede ser que no te resulte lo mismo que te acabo de poner, por que esa es la belleza de los hilos, se ejecutan al mismo tiempo y no sabes en qué orden se están ejecutando.

Otra cosa, te puse todo el rompecabezas, sólo falta que lo pongas en su lugar y te diviertas intentando y probando.